# Connection String for SQL Server 2008 (version 10.0.1600) in Application Configuration File

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, app-config

I am new to create connection string and application configuration file. I use an example which showed connection to SQL Server CE using file which is what I do not want instead I want to connect to SQL Server 2008 Standard edition.

While exploring about connection string on several links like http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ i found that the Connection string uses the Property "Data Source = " and in some places it uses "Server=" which is quiet confusing.

Here is what I have in my application configuration file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShareManagement" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I want someone to tell me which properties need be used and what should be their respective values. (I am using default sa user as UserID and a password and using SQL Server authentication mode. My SQL Server database is installed on same machine/server on which my Visual Studio solution / application reside).

Ragards.

Comment: You can use either `server=` or `Data Source=` (those two are equivalent), and you can use either `database=` or `Initial Catalog=` (again: those are equivalent) - you just need to define **at least** (1) server, (2) database, (3) either integrated security **or** a user id and password for authentication. You need **at least** these three pieces of information

Comment: Explore connection string from http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 8):

You can use either `server=` or `Data Source=` (those two are equivalent), and you can use either `database=` or `Initial Catalog=` (again: those are equivalent) - take your pick, use whatever you prefer.

But you just need to define at least

1. server,
2. database,
3. either `Integrated Security=SSPI` (for integrated, Windows authentication) or `User id=abc;Password=xxxx` for SQL Server authentication

You need at least these three pieces of information.

So if you want to use **integrated security** (Windows authentication), use this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShareManagement" 
         connectionString="server=(local);database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

but if you want to use SQL Server authorization for a user `John` with a password `secret`, use this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShareManagement" 
         connectionString="server=(local);database=AdventureWorks;User ID=John;Password=secret;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Since I'm almost exclusively using these connection strings to connect to a standard relational database server, I personally prefer to use `server=....` and `database=......` - those just seem more natural, clearer and more intuitive to me. But again: you can also use those other key strings - they're **100%** equivalent!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should use the following connection string:

`<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Data Source should be as of the server name, and the initial catalogue will represent the database name you have with your sql server 2008 instance. To get logged in via the integrated security can be a better choice if you have not defined a user/password separately for that particular database except 'sa' account.